# How to access inner content of div or any element in reactjs using useRef Hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

First of all Greeting from my side
I am beginner in Reactjs and I am learning a new hook called useRef() hook.
Basically I am trying to fetch the content of every element present in my div using useRef Hook.
In my code I need to access the content of only p tag how can I achieve it ?
This is my Code :-

```
import React,{useRef} from 'react'

function FormData() {
    const getAllData = useRef(null)

    const onClickHandler = () =>{
        console.log(getAllData.current) 
    }
    
  return (
    <div ref={getAllData} >
        <h1>UseRef Tutorial</h1>
        <p>Abhishek Poddar</p>
        <input type="email"  placeholder='Enter the Email' />
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <input type="password" placeholder='Enter the Password' />
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default FormData
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get text of multiple clicked elements using useRef?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64080555/how-to-get-text-of-multiple-clicked-elements-using-useref)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAllData.current` now is an `element object`. [list of properties and methods](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp)

 you can access its children via `children` property.

```js
const onClickHandler = () => {
    const list = getAllData.current.children;
    for (const e of list) {
      if (e.tagName === "P") {
        console.log(e.textContent);
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: like this : console.log(getAllData.current.children[1].innerText)

Comment: yes, for detail I updated my comment

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if you just need to access the P tag. then you can modify your OnlickHandler something like this.

```
const onClickHandler = () => {
 console.log(getAllData.current.children[1].innerText);
};
```

you can access the current elements' child properties by going through its indexes. So in that case your P tag lies on the 1st index so you can just do and you'll get the P tag.

```
.children[index]
```

Comment: can you elaborate it ?